# Page not found (404) - Django

Tags: django

I have a strange behavior when I try to test my Django on the webpage.
I see what is the error, but I have no clue from where it comes.

What I try to do is :

1. I have project called stockmarket
2. I have application called stockanalysis

the problem is :
when I try to open 'domain/stockmarket I get this:

Page not found (404)

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888//

When I try to open 'domain/stockmarket/stockanalysis'
I get this:

Page not found (404)

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888//stockanalysis/

The issue is clear to me. In both cases I have two slashes (//) instead of one (/).
The issue is - I do not know from where it comes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here some files:

urls.py (project folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stockanalysis/', include('stockanalysis.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

urls.py (app. folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py (app folder)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the index.")
```

setting.py (project folder)

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


SECRET_KEY = '****************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'stockanalysis.apps.StockanalysisConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stockmarket.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stockmarket.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: something similar to [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/twisted-python@twistedmatrix.com/msg02903.html) but what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved.
As I expected nothing wrong was with the files itself (like urls.py or settings.py).
The company which hosts the files did a mistake in vhosts entries in Apache. That's what they told me.
After I created my first Django project I was asked to provide some details, so they could do some adjustments on server side. While doing this they did mistake.